# Backbone how to edit view of an item

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, collections, view

I have two collections stolovi, and racuniTemp. I need to find items in stolovi for each racuniTemp item by the attribute StoloviID... I need to remove "a" tag from the stolovi item view and change img src. I tried doing it a hundred different ways without any success. this is what I have:

```
<div id="stolovi" class="stolovi">  
        <script id="stolTemplate" type ="text/template">
            <div style="margin:3px;">
                <div class='wrapper'>  
                    <a href="#" data-id ="<%= StolID %>"><img id="<%= Opis %>" src="data:image/png;base64,<%= Slika %>"/></a>
                    <div class='description'>  
                         <p class='description_content'><%= Opis %></p>  
                    </div>  
                </div>
             </div>
         </script>    
    </div>  

App.Models.Stol = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: "StolID",
        defaults:
            {
                StolID: 1,
                Opis: "Stol 1",
                Slika: ""
            },
        urlRoot: 'api/stolovi'
    });

    App.Collections.Stolovi = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Stol,
        url: 'api/stolovi',
        //    obrisiA: function(id) {
        //        filtered = this.filter(function(stol) {
        //            return stol.get("StolID") === id;
        //        });
        //    return new App.Collections.Stolovi(filtered);
        //},
        });


    App.Views.Stol = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',

        template: _.template( $('#stolTemplate').html() ),

        initialize: function () {

        },

        render: function (id) {
            //if (this.model.attributes.StolID = id) {
            //    this.children.find("img").attr('src', '../Images/xsoftLogo.png');

            //}
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });


//var promijeniSliku = function (view) {
//    view.$el.img.src = "~/Images/xsoftLogo.png";
//}

//var stoloviFilt = stolovi.obrisiA(model.attributes.StolID);
//var viewZauzetiStolovi = new App.Views.Artikli({ collection: stoloviFilt });
//viewZauzetiStolovi.each(promijeniSliku, this);

    var racuniTemp = new App.Collections.RacuniTemp();
    //var viewRacuniTemp = new App.Views.RacuniTemp({ collection: racuniTemp });
    racuniTemp.fetch({
        success: function () {
            //racuniTemp.each(prikaziRacune, this);
        }
    });

    //var stl = document.getElementById('Stol 1');
    //var pct= $stl.find("a").getAttribute('data-id', '24');
    //pct.find("img").attr("src", "~/Images/xsoftLogo.png");
```

Thank you for any kind of help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved out this using jquery. I'm not sure is this a good resolution for the problem.

```
 var slika = $('#stolovi #stolWrapper[data-id=' + model.attributes.StolID + '] img');
slika.attr('src', 'Images/account_and_control.png');
$('#stolovi #stolWrapper[data-id=' + model.attributes.StolID + ']').bind('click #stolWrapper', function () { return false; });
```